# Get value from radio button Angular Material Dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have Angular Material dialog , where I updating table clicking change status.

I need to get value from radio button in my dialog

Here is full working example

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9rbj1

Here is code of component

```
   import {Component, Inject, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialog} from "@angular/material";
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import { Payment } from '../payments/payment';


@Component({
    selector: 'editing-dialog',
    templateUrl: './editing-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editing-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class EditingDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    reason:String;
    id: Number;
    statusdescription: String ;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditingDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data:Payment) {
            this.reason = data.Reason;
            this.id  = data.Id;
            this.statusdescription = data.StatusDescription;
            this.form = fb.group({
                reason: [this.reason, Validators.required],
                id: this.id,
                status: this.statusdescription
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    save() {
        this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
    }

    close() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

And here is it's html

```
<h2>{{description}}</h2>

<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">

    <mat-form-field>

        <input matInput min="0" max="100" required placeholder="Payment Reason" formControlName="reason" value="{{reason}}">

    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-radio-group>
        <mat-radio-button value="Approve">Approve</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="Reject">Reject</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group> </mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>

    <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="save()">
        Ok
    </button>



    <button class="mat-raised-button"
            (click)="close()">
        Close
    </button>

</mat-dialog-actions>
```

So when I click radio button I need to get the value of clicked radio button in answer.

So status needs to be radio button

How I can do this correctly?

Comment: Why haven't you assigned your radio buttons to form controls?

Comment: I'm new in Angular, so don't know, how to do it right. @cale_b

Comment: My point is: be consistent? You have it assigned for your payment reason input, you also need to do it for your radio inputs.  Forms aren't simple in angular, but there's lots and lots of examples / documentation on the web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are using reactive forms, use `formControlName` on `mat-radio-group` just like you did on `matInput` field. I have forked and updated your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djch5k?file=src%2Fapp%2Feditingdialog%2Fediting-dialog.component.html) which now logs the radio button value on the console as well when you click save button. You can get and use this value where you want in you payments component.

Comment: Thank's for help. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your TS file:

```js
@Input()
name: string
```

And this in your HTML file:

```html
<mat-radio-group name="status" ngModel #status="ngModel">
   <mat-radio-button value="Approve">Approve</mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button value="Reject">Reject</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```